# SQLquery optimization with left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my query for getting the chat conversation. I have two tables Team_Messages and Resources. I have foreignkey in Resources with reference to Team_Message_Id.

I want to optimize this query using indexing(if possible) as it is taking much time to retrieve the data. If it can be done using indexing which columns should I index.

(Team_Channel_Id is foreignKey in table Team_Messages with reference to Team_Channel)

```
SELECT * FROM  Team_Messages tm  
LEFT JOIN  Resources r  
   ON tm.Team_Message_Id = r.Message_Id 
WHERE tm.Team_Channel_Id  = 1241 
ORDER BY tm.CreatedOn DESC OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: I did a brief search and found [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56/how-to-determine-if-an-index-is-required-or-necessary) relevant answer.

Comment: Do you really need to return all columns (SELECT *)? A narrower result set would make it possible to create a covering index for the query.

Comment: You need to provide the execution plan, using Paste The Plan, if you want performance assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up the query with the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on team_messages (team_channel_id); -- if it doesn't exist

create index ix2 on resources (message_id, createdon);
```

The first index probably already exists since it seems it corresponds to the primary key of the table.

Answer (score -1):

On fist look, you can create index like this
Team_Messages(Team_Message_Id, Team_Channel_Id,  CreatedOn)
Resources (Message_id)
because excecution plan usually use **one** index for **one** table in **one** select .
But MS SQL use statistic for query plan and can make sort in memory if result set are not large. In this case you can use light index
Team_Messages(Team_Message_Id, Team_Channel_Id)
Resources (Message_id)
Your case looks like this https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/index-merge-performance